# if statements inside mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, sql-insert, database-trigger

So i have two tables practice and practice1 where both has an auto increment id and a name and surname columns. 
I made an after insert trigger where i have an if statement inside, where i put a condition if name is null one insert should occur and if surname is null then the other one but it did not work for some reason. I am sharing the script i tried.

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `id_information`.`practice_after_INSERT1` AFTER INSERT ON `practice` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
if (`name`  = NULL) then
 insert into id_information.practice1(surname) values(new.surname);
 else
 (`surname` = NULL) then
  insert into id_information.practice1(name) values(new.name);
 end if;
END$$
delimiter ;
```

Kindly correct my mistake. id_information is the name of the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the syntax you want is:

```
delimiter $$

create definer = current_user trigger `id_information`.`practice_after_insert1` 
after insert on `practice` for each row
begin
    if new.name is null then
        insert into id_information.practice1(surname) values(new.surname);
    elseif new.surname is null then
        insert into id_information.practice1(name) values(new.name);
    end if;
end$$

delimiter ;
```

Key points:

- you need to use pseudo-table `new` to access the row that was just inserted
- the structure of your `if` statement should be `if ... then ... elseif ... end`
- to check a value against `null`, use `is null` rather than `= null` (which is never true)